# Get first monday of month for a given set of datetimes

Tags: php, datetime

### What I Require

I have a certain list of datetimes. I want to get the first monday of each datetimes.

eg: Suppose the given datetimes are

```
 2013-07-05 2013-08-05, 2013-09-13 etc.
```

I want to get the first monday of all these datetimes such that the output results in

```
 2013-07-01, 2013-08-05, 2013-09-02 respectively
```

I am actually stuck with this using `stftime`.

```
strftime("%d/%m/%Y", strtotime("first Monday of July 2012"));
```

Comment: please make me clear why the question as voted offtopic so that I can make sure I dont make the same mistake again

Comment: I have not downvoted you but who ever did, did for the reason "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" as he also marked it to close. Attention to the bold part.

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this on SO. Look to the right (under "Related"). You should also use the search (top right on the page) before asking a question. When you create a question you are also presented with similar questions.

Comment: You mean the first day of the month? `2013-09-13` => `2013-09-02`

Comment: OK, I got you.Try my code, hope that will be what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using php Datetime class:

```
$Dates = array('2013-07-02', '2013-08-05', '2013-09-13');
foreach ($Dates as $Date)
{
    $test = new DateTime($Date);
    echo $test->modify('first monday')->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: This is actually not the correct answer to this question. `$test->modify('first monday');` will update the DateTime object to the next monday. In some cases you will end up with a monday in the next month. The right way to modify the DateTime object is by doing this: `$test->modify('first monday of this month');`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and my answer is not 100% solution for this question, but this might be usefull for someone, this will give "first Saturday of the given year/month":

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("First Saturday of 2021-08")); // gives: 2021-08-07
```

You can manipulate this in many ways.

obviously you can put "Second Saturday of year-month" and it will find that as well.

Works with PHP 5.3.0 and above (tested at https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function find_the_first_monday($date)
{
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $year = date('Y', $time);
    $month = date('m', $time);

    for($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++)
    {
        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
        if (date('N', $time) == 1)
        {
            return date('Y-m-d', $time);
        }
    }
}

echo find_the_first_monday('2013-07-05'), "\n";
echo find_the_first_monday('2013-08-05'), "\n";
echo find_the_first_monday('2013-09-13'), "\n";

// output:
// 2013-07-01
// 2013-08-05
// 2013-09-02
```

Answer (score 0):

the first monday would be within the first 7 days of a month, 
`DAYOFWEEK(date)` returns 1=sunday, 2=monday, and so on

also see the hack#23
http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlhks/chapter/ch04.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You could loop  through the array of dates and then break out of the loop and return the `$Date` when you first encounter Monday

[PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f01-zx1)

```
$Dates = array('2013-07-02', '2013-08-05', '2013-09-13');

foreach ($Dates as $Date)
{
    $weekday = date('l', strtotime($Date));
    if($weekday == 'Monday') { 
        echo "First Monday in list is - " . $Date;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Output

`First Monday in list is - 2013-08-05`