# Getting first monday of month from given datetime dosenot retain the time component

Tags: php, datetime

### What I am Trying

*Reference: [Get first monday of month for a given set of datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041116/get-first-monday-of-month-for-a-given-set-of-datetimes)*

I am trying to get the first monday of month based on the datetimes given.

Eg: Consider the datetimes `2013-08-02 00:00; 2013-09-05 00:00`. Then the result will be `2013-08-05 00:00; 2013-09-02 00:00` respectively.

I am able to do upto this point but it dosenot retain the time component.

### What I require

In the above eg: if the two datetimes contains a time value say  `2013-08-02 10:00; 2013-09-05 10:00`. Then the output should be `2013-08-05 10:00; 2013-09-02 10:00`. But I am getting  `2013-08-05 00:00; 2013-09-02 00:00` from my code. What can I possibly do to solve this?

### Code

```
 $test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
 echo $test->modify('first monday')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: You mean you want to retain the time component?

Comment: Yes, thats what I require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retain the time at 10:00, try:

```
$test = new DateTime('2013-08-02 10:00');
echo $test->modify('first monday ' . $test->format('H:i'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
echo strftime("%d/%m/%Y", strtotime("first Monday of Aug 2013"));
```

Comment: That will return 05/08/2013 only. Also it would be better if I get a fix using Datetime class.

Comment: This date is Monday in Aug 2013.

Comment: Please try my code, it also gives the same. but its not about  monday its about the time component.